# Anomaly Detection on Multiple Correlated Timeseries data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection

I'm just trying to put together a simple algorithm to detect anomalies on multiple correlated timeseries data.

Imagine the following timeseries data points:

```
t1=a1,b1,c1
t2=a2,b2,c2
t3=a3,b3,c3
t4=a4,b4,c4
t5=a5,b5,c5
....
```

Assumption is a, b, c are highly correlated.

I'd decompose the individual timeseries of a, b, c using STL decomposition and I would get the residual timeseries (with seasonal and noise removed) respectively.

Let's say they are: A,B,C (Residual timeseries).

```
t1=A1,B1,C1
t2=A2,B2,C2
t3=A3,B3,C3
...
```

To pass the data to the anomaly detector, is it practical to average the every data point and use this as a final residual data. So the final data becomes:

```
t1=AVG(A1,B1,C1)
t2=AVG(A2,B2,C2)
t3=AVG(A3,B3,C3)
...
```

What are the pros and cons and any suggestions to solve this type of problem?